# Rotate text in a canvas with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, rotation

In the following code i want to rotate the text of each element of the array in javascript. If i use for example `ctx.rotate(Math.PI/10)` before the filltext, it rotates all the elements. The positioning of the text also changes with `ctx.rotate(Math.PI/10)` and if i use 90 degrees, `ctx.rotate(Math.PI/2)` the text does not show on the canvas.

```
<html>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="300" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
<script>
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var x = new Array("Day1","Day2","Day3","Day4","Day5");

    ctx.rotate(Math.PI/10);
        for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
            ctx.fillText(x[i],i*50+20,50);      
        }   


</script>
</html>
```

As i said, i want to rotate each element on its own and with that the positioning of each element should stay the same as in the non-rotated text as in the code above. Thus each element has to rotate around its own axis. How can i achieve this?

Comment: You should define a tau constant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have made some changes in your code, it should help:

```js
<html>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="300" style="border:1px solid 

#d3d3d3;"></canvas>
<script>
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var x = new Array("Day1","Day2","Day3","Day4","Day5");
       for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
            var size = ctx.measureText(x[i]);
    ctx.save();
    var tx = (i*50+20) + (size.width/2);
    var ty = (50);
    ctx.translate(tx,ty);
    ctx.rotate(Math.PI / 10);
    ctx.translate(-tx,-ty);
            ctx.fillText(x[i],i*50+20,50);
    ctx.restore();
        }   
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/YyN2P/

A brief overview:

- context.translate to where you want the rotation point of the text
- context.rotate
- context.fillText with an X offset == 1/2 the text width and Y offset == 1/2 the text height
- (you can context.measureText to measure the text width)
- wrap all this in context.save and context.restore.
- use requestAnimationFrame to drive your animation.

And some example code:

```
var word1="Day1";
var word1Width=ctx.measureText(word1).width;

var r=0;
animate();

function animate(){
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    r+=Math.PI/180;
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(100,100);
    ctx.rotate(r);
    ctx.fillText(word1,-word1Width/2,4);
    ctx.restore();
}
```

Comment: So you're just hardcoding half the text height to be 4px?